# Attempt to read from field 'java.lang.String com.indooratlas.android.FloorPlan.url' on a null object reference

Tags: android

I want to draw circle as an icon to show current location.

But error occurs as in this question Title.

```
public void onServiceUpdate(ServiceState state) {    
FloorPlan floorPlan = null;
    BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    options.inDither = true;
    options.inScaled = false;
    options.inPreferredConfig = Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888;
    FutureResult<Bitmap> result = mIndoorAtlas.fetchFloorPlanImage(floorPlan, options);  <---- line 257 ---
    result.setCallback(new ResultCallback<Bitmap>() {
        @Override
        public void onResult(final Bitmap result) {
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);
                    Bitmap bitmapCircle = Bitmap.createBitmap(result.getWidth(), result.getHeight(), result.getConfig());
                    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmapCircle);
                    Paint paint = new Paint();
                    paint.setAntiAlias(true);
                    paint.setColor(Color.BLUE);
                    paint.setStrokeWidth(10);
                    canvas.drawBitmap(result, new Matrix(), null);
                    canvas.drawCircle(i, j, 10, paint);
                    imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmapCircle);
                }
            });

        }
```

And this is the error statement :

Attempt to read from field 'java.lang.String com.indooratlas.android.FloorPlan.url' on a null object reference
            at com.indooratlas._internal.cd.fetchFloorPlanImage
at skripsi.ubm.studenttracking.indoor.onServiceUpdate (indoor.java:257)

As my speculation is in Floorplan floorplan = null.

Answer (score 0):

That method requires a non-null first argument. Don't call it with a null argument.